# Animated dot plot in shiny

Tags: r, animation, plot, shiny

Can you suggest a way to add an animated dot plot / stripchart to `shiny` please.

The figure I am trying to add is

```
x = sample(1:10, 100, TRUE)

for(i in seq_along(x)){
  stripchart(x[1:i], method="stack", at=0.05, frame.plot=FALSE, xaxt="n", xlim=range(x))
  axis(1, pretty(x))
  Sys.sleep(0.05)
}
```

(ideally I'd like it faster than 0.05, but R baulks)

When I try to do this in `shiny`, it delays and then plots in a single move.
(`ggplotly` [doesn't seem like an option](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1213))

---

Test `shiny` code:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage( plotOutput("plot") )

server = function(input, output, session) {
  x = sample(1:10, 100, TRUE)
  rng = range(x)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      for(i in seq_along(x)){
      stripchart(x[1:i], method="stack", at=0.05, frame.plot=FALSE, 
                 pch=16, cex=2, xaxt="n", xlim=rng)
      axis(1, pretty(x))
      Sys.sleep(0.05)
      }})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can do an animation with a slider. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html

Comment: thanks for the link @StéphaneLaurent -- I'll have a look. Currently messing about with gifs!!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not hesitate to notify me if you need help with the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following advice from Stéphane Laurent to use [sliders](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html) in the side panel, you can use the slider values to subset the data that is passed to `stripchart`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(    
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("animation", "Looping Animation:",
                  min = 0, max = 100,
                  value = 1, step = 10,
                  animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = FALSE))
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
    ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  x = sample(1:10, 100, TRUE)

  sliderValues <- reactive({ (input$animation)})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      stripchart(x[1:sliderValues()], method="stack", at=0.05, frame.plot=FALSE, 
           pch=16, cex=2, xaxt="n", xlim=range(x))
      axis(1, pretty(x))
  })    
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```